# JavaScript: Regex for one letter and a point

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Using Javascript, I am trying to split a text using a regular expression that contains only one letter and a point; for example 'A.' or 'Q.'
I am using: array[0].split(/[A-Z]+./);
But it is returning true if there are multiple characters like 'AA.' or 'ZZ.'

What is the regex for one character only? I also have access to jQuery.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `/[A-Z]{1}+./`?

Comment: please add some examples.

Comment: @LucasCosta why the `+` after `{1}`?

Comment: @empiric no reason, that's a mistake, I think should be `/[A-Z]{1}\./`. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: `array[0].split(/([A-Z]{1}\.)/);`

Explanation:
`[A-Z]{1}` - this looks for any single letter
`\.` - this looks for a `.` note that you'll need the backslash as a `.` in a regex means any character.
These are surrounded by brackets so that you are looking for the sequence:
`one letter followed by a .`

You'll need to remove the + as it means one or more. if you want to find several occorances then you'll need the global flag (g at the end): `array[0].split(/([A-Z]{1}\.)/g);`

Limit to A. and not AA.
If you want to make sure its only one letter follow by a . and not match on the end of `AA.` then you can use the word boundary like so: `array[0].split(/\b([A-Z]{1}\.)/);`

This site is amazing for helping with regex: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but, isn't `{1}` redundant?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `+`, as it means "one or more". Just remove it. Also you have to escape the `.` otherwise it means "any character".

If you want to match only a capital letter and a point, this should do the trick : `/[A-Z]\./g` if you want the regex to be case insensitive, simply add the `i` flag : `/[A-Z]\./gi`. Remove the `g` flag if you only want to match the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
one

```
/\s[A-Z]\.\s/g
```